# How to convert an SPSS Macro which checks for Numbers to check for a Letter and a Number?

Tags: macros, spss

Working with an SPSS spreadsheet that contains mixed data. One column contains varied numeric entries by row. I wrote a simple macro that has the following behavior.

1. Checks each Row for a given numeric entry in a column.
2. A new column is then created and, if the numeric entry is in the row it is assigned a 1. If not it is assigned 0.

The code is as follows:

```
DEFINE INCHECK (!POSITIONAL !TOKENS(1)
/!POSITIONAL !CMDEND)

NUMERIC !1.
COUNT !1=IN1 TO IN15 (!2).
IF !1 GT 0
!1=1.
!ENDDEFINE
```

The problem is as follows. I now have a new dataset which has an additional column with data like "E1567, G4345, etc." I would like to adjust the macro to be able to have the same behavior with this different type of entry. I've though about converting the entries, but am unsure how to accomplish this in SPSS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Before referring to the problem, I can suggest a general improvement to the macro. This can replace the macro content: `compute !1=any(!2, IN1 TO IN15) .`

Answer (score 0):

From your examples I understand your new text variables are made up of one letter and then a few digits. If this is consistent in all cases (if not, please give more examples), you can use this simple conversion before going back to use the same macro:

```
compute YourTextVar=char.substr(YourTextVar,2,20).
alter type YourTextVar(f20).
```

Comment: Hey Eli, I apologize for not being more specific. The behavior of this code seems to be such that the variable, which is as you inferred a letter followed by a number, is converted from a string to a numeric. What I'd like is for the INCHECK to recognize the string as-is, rather than convert it to a numeric. Does that make sense?

Comment: I guess I don't really understand the problem - one of the IN1 TO IN15 columns is now text, and the value you're looking for may sometimes be a number and sometimes a string?
also - do you need the macro to adjust to new files with unexpected number and names of text variables, of just to this new specific dataset?